# Twilio Python CSV SMS sending only one text not full list

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, sms

I have been messing around with putting together a Python 3.9 script that sends mass text messages. The CSV has two colums, Phone Number column A and a custom message Column B. The code runs the first number with the first message, but stops before going to line 2. I have on average 50 messages that need to be sent per day each morning. Hoping someone can shoot over an idea to get it running the full CSV.

For the CSV it is very simple:

```
phone_number, new_message
+1757000000, Hey Beth Happy birthday
+1573800000, Hi Jake, blah blah blah
etc etc
```

Here is the code I have put together so far:

```
import twilio
from twilio.rest import Client
from pandas import *

AUTH_SID = 'XXXXXXX' 
AUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXXX'  


token = AUTH_TOKEN
sid = AUTH_SID

tclient = Client(sid, token)

data = read_csv("call.csv")  
phone = data['phone_number'].tolist()
talk = data['new_message'].tolist()

message = tclient.messages.create(
    to = phone,
    from_ = '+1571000000', 
    body = talk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You will need to iterate over the items in your dataframe in order to send a message for each of them. There seem to be a [bunch of ways to iterate like this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/), but here's my suggestion:

```py
data = read_csv("call.csv")  

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    message = tclient.messages.create(
        to = row['phone_number'],
        from_ = '+1571000000', 
        body = row['new_message'])
```